# List of public US (NYSE, Nasdaq) companies that filed for bankruptcy in the last 10 years

Tags: data, market-data, historical-data

I am working on a Data Science project on bankruptcy prediction. I am looking for a list of listed US companies that filed for bankruptcy in the last 10 years but I am really struggling to find any information at all. I have tried several services (including Eikon/Refinitiv) but to no avail.

Many thanks in advance,

Fred

Answer (score 1):

These data are reported on SEC Form 8-K and are available from [Sharadar](https://www.quantrocket.com/pricing/data/sharadar/). The [QuantRocket documentation](https://www.quantrocket.com/docs/#fundamental-sharadar-sec-form-8-k) shows how to use the data and the available event codes.

Answer (score 1):

Bloomberg's BCY  lists all the U.S. bankruptcies with the filter to choose all and then you can export the data and sort it according to your requirements.